# $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{xF\left(x\right)}{e^{x^2}}\right)$ where $F$ is a primitive function of $e^{x^2}$.

Tags: analysis, limits

> Let $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and F its primitive. Calculate the following limit:
>
> $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{xF\left(x\right)}{e^{x^2}}\right)$$

Couldn't figure this one out yet, the answer being $0$. Can I have some hints on how to approach it? Thank you.

Comment: Do you see how continuity could help?

Comment: The limit is obtained by simply plugging $x=0$ because all functions involved are continuous and denominator is non-zero on plugging $x=0$. On plugging you get the answer as $0\cdot F(0)/1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0} xF(x)=0$. Can you continue?

To see this, use that $F(x)=\int e^{x^2} dx$ is continuous and bounded near zero.

Comment: I don't get why that limit is 0... Could you please expend a bit?

Comment: @Alexander; See the edit.